# A question on operator theory

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $T$ be a quasinilpotent operator acting on a separable Hilbert space $H$. Fix a vector $x$ in $H$ such that $[T^n x]=H$ (the closed span of the orbit is $H$), and a hyperplane $Z\subset H$. Can we always find (for any choice of $x$ and $Z$) a scalar $\lambda\neq 0$ such that $x\in (\lambda I-T)Z$?

Comment: Hyperplane means subspace of codimension 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is no. Take $T$ to be a weighted right shift, with weights $(\mu_i)$ converging fast to $0$ (a so called Donoghue operator). Then $T$ is quasinilpotent (and compact). Take $x=e_1$, and $Z=[e_k]_{k\geq 2}$. Then for any $\lambda\neq 0$ we have that 
$$
(\lambda I-T)^{-1}e_1=\frac{1}{\lambda}e_1+\frac{1}{\lambda^2}\mu_2e_2+\frac{1}{\lambda^3}\mu_3e_3+\dots
$$
Therefore, for any $\lambda\neq 0$ we have that $(\lambda I-T)^{-1}e_1\notin Z$.

Comment: I think that your $T$ is not quasinilpotent because $\sigma(T)\ne \{0\}$. The spectrum of the right shift is the unit disk. Does quasinilpotent mean something different to you than $\sigma(T)=\{0\}$?

Comment: You are right, but we can take a weighted right shift instead, with the weights converging fast to $0$. Then $T$ will be compact, quasinilpotent.